# Line Breaks Prevent BeautifulSoup from Extracting Data

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, imaplib

My script grabs HTML code from an email inbox via `imaplib`, passes it through `BeautifulSoup` and tries to extract all the `href`s in there.

```
rv, data = M.SEARCH(None, '(FROM "foo@bar.com")')
if rv == 'OK':
    for num in data[0].split():
        typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        html = data[0][1]

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
            print a['href']
```

However the `html` variable contains HTML code that have a new line every `N` characters, preventing BeautifulSoup from accurately returning the `href`, especially long ones that have been split up by the new line.

Theres also strange characters like `=0D` and `3D` everywhere.

```
messages, <a=0D
href=3D"http://links.google.com/wf/click?upn=3DOGGGYNMPA980E3DmngbHusD=
Uo-2BK17XLM3ogFJfQXXXfMWZLdsQSSVv33HbPoHPXGcH8tSf9ZFFU5i-2FrV4O6ISlpDCIVaN5=
83xr1CGoa5yxZimagE5JiSUAhbZH8P7WiNvf35BsXrCxmrmRLMGB-2BJAQ-3D-3D_IcMuwcQVVt=
a699aeVjRRVxwBCNHkXaWO-2FyIlAqZ7CPsryDB24UVYZbMIvGLJb13chayC-2FLeucv-2FTrko=
7LaiaWHkzy85DWXrK1olI1SEJZs-2BMCAWfoVfloGJivlLSH0GQk0XeVT0j383tZrsymuWLF0S2=
q5j3LR91e76dRXQe7p8t5CgrBe-2FqGk6bmURG9XCNw3dwpHnymaR-2FggHQx6GnbbueF7PVp2H=
-2BGoHUEkMOSXJ8FfSgQIiGICvxz1zcBJPw-2FRoE3YDl-2By8XETkXjVaNchNA1ZN8FDCD5VUf=
V9oUOnavAirXX-2FEw1THfSpV4VYDX">unsubscribe</a></td>=0D
                </tr>=0D
                <tr>=0D
                    <td height=3D"12"></td>=0D
                </tr>=0D
```

What can we do to solve this problem?

Comment: You can try extracting the `href`s using regex, without depending on `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [quopri](https://docs.python.org/2/library/quopri.html) to decode the [Quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) data:

*Quoted-Printable, or QP encoding, is an encoding using printable ASCII characters (alphanumeric and the equals sign "=") to transmit 8-bit data over a 7-bit data path or, generally, over a medium which is not 8-bit clean.[1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/quopri.html) It is defined as a MIME content transfer encoding for use in e-mail.*

*QP works by using the equals sign "=" as an escape character. It also limits line length to 76, as some software has limits on line length.*

```
html = """<a=0D
href=3D"http://links.google.com/wf/click?upn=3DOGGGYNMPA980E3DmngbHusD=
Uo-2BK17XLM3ogFJfQXXXfMWZLdsQSSVv33HbPoHPXGcH8tSf9ZFFU5i-2FrV4O6ISlpDCIVaN5=
83xr1CGoa5yxZimagE5JiSUAhbZH8P7WiNvf35BsXrCxmrmRLMGB-2BJAQ-3D-3D_IcMuwcQVVt=
a699aeVjRRVxwBCNHkXaWO-2FyIlAqZ7CPsryDB24UVYZbMIvGLJb13chayC-2FLeucv-2FTrko=
7LaiaWHkzy85DWXrK1olI1SEJZs-2BMCAWfoVfloGJivlLSH0GQk0XeVT0j383tZrsymuWLF0S2=
q5j3LR91e76dRXQe7p8t5CgrBe-2FqGk6bmURG9XCNw3dwpHnymaR-2FggHQx6GnbbueF7PVp2H=
-2BGoHUEkMOSXJ8FfSgQIiGICvxz1zcBJPw-2FRoE3YDl-2By8XETkXjVaNchNA1ZN8FDCD5VUf=
V9oUOnavAirXX-2FEw1THfSpV4VYDX">unsubscribe</a></td>=0D
                </tr>=0D
                <tr>=0D
                    <td height=3D"12"></td>=0D
                </tr>=0D"""


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import quopri

soup = BeautifulSoup(quopri.decodestring(html), "lxml")
print(soup)
print(soup.select_one("a")["href"])
```

Will output:

```
<html><body><a href="http://links.google.com/wf/click?upn=OGGGYNMPA980E3DmngbHusDUo-2BK17XLM3ogFJfQXXXfMWZLdsQSSVv33HbPoHPXGcH8tSf9ZFFU5i-2FrV4O6ISlpDCIVaN583xr1CGoa5yxZimagE5JiSUAhbZH8P7WiNvf35BsXrCxmrmRLMGB-2BJAQ-3D-3D_IcMuwcQVVta699aeVjRRVxwBCNHkXaWO-2FyIlAqZ7CPsryDB24UVYZbMIvGLJb13chayC-2FLeucv-2FTrko7LaiaWHkzy85DWXrK1olI1SEJZs-2BMCAWfoVfloGJivlLSH0GQk0XeVT0j383tZrsymuWLF0S2q5j3LR91e76dRXQe7p8t5CgrBe-2FqGk6bmURG9XCNw3dwpHnymaR-2FggHQx6GnbbueF7PVp2H-2BGoHUEkMOSXJ8FfSgQIiGICvxz1zcBJPw-2FRoE3YDl-2By8XETkXjVaNchNA1ZN8FDCD5VUfV9oUOnavAirXX-2FEw1THfSpV4VYDX">unsubscribe</a>
<tr>
<td height="12"></td>
</tr> </body></html>
http://links.google.com/wf/click?upn=OGGGYNMPA980E3DmngbHusDUo-2BK17XLM3ogFJfQXXXfMWZLdsQSSVv33HbPoHPXGcH8tSf9ZFFU5i-2FrV4O6ISlpDCIVaN583xr1CGoa5yxZimagE5JiSUAhbZH8P7WiNvf35BsXrCxmrmRLMGB-2BJAQ-3D-3D_IcMuwcQVVta699aeVjRRVxwBCNHkXaWO-2FyIlAqZ7CPsryDB24UVYZbMIvGLJb13chayC-2FLeucv-2FTrko7LaiaWHkzy85DWXrK1olI1SEJZs-2BMCAWfoVfloGJivlLSH0GQk0XeVT0j383tZrsymuWLF0S2q5j3LR91e76dRXQe7p8t5CgrBe-2FqGk6bmURG9XCNw3dwpHnymaR-2FggHQx6GnbbueF7PVp2H-2BGoHUEkMOSXJ8FfSgQIiGICvxz1zcBJPw-2FRoE3YDl-2By8XETkXjVaNchNA1ZN8FDCD5VUfV9oUOnavAirXX-2FEw1THfSpV4VYDX
```

If you print the hex chars *3D* and *0D*, you can see it all makes sense:

```
In [4]: print("\x3D")
=

In [5]: print("\x0D")


In [6]:
```

Comment: So *that's* why the [base64](http://linux.die.net/man/1/base64) utility on Linux wraps lines after the 76th character unless you add `--wrap=0` or `-w 0`! Thanks :)